# ¿Cómo obtener los el código original de un proyecto vuejs con webpack?

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, webpack

Tengo un proyecto desarrollado en **vuejs, nodejs y webpack** para hacerle correcciones y mantenimiento.

Todo el código fuente del proyecto esta en **webpacks**, lo que lo hace difícil de modificar y darle mantenimiento.

Desde los archivos webpack, ¿cómo se puede tener acceso al código fuente original para poder modificar?

Comment: js no va compilado, es interpretado, por lo tanto todo lo que necesitas esta ahi.. solo que vas a tener que buscarlo...

Comment: gracias, voy a hacer así.